# Dynamically change name of SSRS Report

Tags: reporting-services

I need a way to dynamically change a reports file name based on a parameter it is given.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ironically, I got a email from my Subscription to SqlServerCentral with a perfect solution for this problem about a month after posting this question.

It requires a little modification of the Reporting database, here is a link:

http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/Reporting+Services+(SSRS)/69546/

Comment: This is so not helpful.  Consider adding details of how you did it to help others who may find themselves in a similar situation.

Comment: Here, I found the link I used to solve the problem and edited it in to my post.